# c++ dtor to free _bstr_t memory

Tags: c++, bstr

A simple question but I am not sure what it is done in C++.

When I have a class that have _bstr_t member.
I would like to know if does member are freed when the object is deleted:

```
class A {
    _bstr_t foo("Testing");
}
```

The `A` class does not have a dtor. So is the default dtor calling the dtor of yeach member of the class `A`?

Especially for _bstr_t because it allocate a string via SysAllocString.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `_bstr_t` destructor will have been called - the compiler will take care of that. Even though it doesn't have a user-defined destructor the compiler will emit code that destroys all fully constructed subobjects by calling their destructors.

Since `_bstr_t` has a non-trivial destructor that takes care of calling `SysFreeString()` that destructor will be called and release the BSTR.